# Letters and numbers... Replace the question mark

Tags: cipher, pattern

Here's some letters and numbers. Find "?"

**(S,V):3::(U,K):16::(T,F):5::(L,K):5::(M,W):1::(I,O,M):?**

Hint1:

> Its **NOT** A-Z=1-26 related

Hint2:

> Three operations; +, -, ^

Ok, this is a minor give away,...

> S=1 (Why do you think this is the case?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is:

> Number of lines in each letter.
>  `S=1, V=2. (1+2)^(2-1) = 3^1 = 3`
>  `U=1, K=3. (1+3)^(3-1) = 4^2 = 16`
>  `T=2, F=3. (2+3)^(3-2) = 5^1 = 5`
>  `L=2, K=3. (2+3)^(3-2) = 5^1 = 5`
>  `M=4, W=4. (4+4)^(4-4) = 8^0 = 1`

and

> `I=1 O=1, M=4. (1+1+4)^(4-1-1) = 6^2 = 36`
>  (Or something similar, it is not certain how to do it, since there is no example of 3 elements)

Comment: This is correct :) 36 was the intended answer.